# Connecting to wifi Ubuntu 16.04 wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I have problems connecting to wifi. I downloaded the drivers - iwlwifi Wireless 7260, and copied them in /lib/firmware but it doesn't seem to help. I don't even have any wifi networks, because on the dropdown menu it says that wifi is disabled 
[network menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xsqA.png). I have exhausted most options online and I don't know what to do now. ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to add results for `rfkill list all`

Comment: Usually, "Disabled" indicates that the wireless switch or key combination is set to turn off the wireless radio. What brand of laptop is it? Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Too enable wifi run this in an terminal:
  `nmcli radio all on`

For more options look at the manpage of nmcli.

Answer (score 0):

January 8, 2018

I'm installing Lubuntu 16.04 on Dell Inspiron.

When I boot to the live drive, the wifi works fine. When I install the operating system without updates, it works fine. When I do the updates, it dies and nothing I've found in over 10 similar questions had answers that solved the problem.

I reinstalled Lubuntu directly, and it works long enough to install, then doesn't work when it boots the installed OS when I included updates.

I reinstalled Lubuntu directly and didn't include updates and it worked until I did updates.

I finally booted from the live drive, installed without updates and then ***manually ran updates.  This time, I unchecked the networking box and I still have wifi after all the updates.***

The moral of this story is that if it works don't !@#$%^ with it!